# Copying values from one dataframe slice to another: are slices from multi-indexed pandas dataframes using `IndexSlice` always ordered consistently?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

## Context

Say I have a multi-indexed dataframe as follows:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

arrays = [
    ["bar", "bar", "baz", "baz", "foo", "foo", "qux", "qux"],
    ["one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two", "one", "two"],
]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=["first", "second"])
data = np.array([
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6],
    [7, 8],
    [9, 10],
    [11, 12],
    [13, 14],
    [15, 16],
])
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=('a', 'b'))
```

which looks something like this:

```py
               a   b
first second        
bar   one      1   2
      two      3   4
baz   one      5   6
      two      7   8
foo   one      9  10
      two     11  12
qux   one     13  14
      two     15  16
```

I would like to copy the values of column `a` for the first index level `bar` into the same column for the first index level `qux`, *aligned on the second level of the index* (here called `second`). In other words, I would like to obtain the following dataframe from the one above:

```py
               a   b
first second        
bar   one      1   2
      two      3   4
baz   one      5   6
      two      7   8
foo   one      9  10
      two     11  12
qux   one      1  14  # <-- column a changed to match first = bar for second = one
      two      3  16  # <-- column a changed to match first = bar for second = two
```

I understand based on the answer given to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56601019/insert-into-a-pandas-dataframe-slice-of-another-slice-from-the-same-dataframe) question I can accomplish this by using `pd.IndexSlice` in conjunction with `.loc` and `.values` as follows:

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['qux', :], 'a'] = df.loc[pd.IndexSlice['bar', :], 'a'].values
```

I don't intuitively like this (perhaps/probably unjustifiably) as it's not immediately clear to me if the values will **always** be aligned on the second index level or not:

## Question:

Can I *guarantee* that the above assignment (accessing using `.values`) will *always* be aligned on the second level of the multi-index?

If not, is there a way of accomplishing what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: What to you mean by "aligned on the second index level"?

Comment: In the above example, I'm interested in knowing if the slice accessed via `loc` as above will always be ordered as `one`, `two` (on the second level of the multi-index). In general, I'm interested in knowing if this holds for far more than two level values for similar problems.

Comment: No, it won't be aligned, because by using `.values` (which btw is deprecated in favor of `.to_numpy()`), you remove any index/column information.

Comment: If that answers your question, I'll write up a real answer.

Comment: I think that the real question is "how can I make an assignment that  will always be aligned on the second level of the multi-index?"

Comment: Do you know the answer to that, @hpchavaz? I'm curious.

Comment: Thanks both. I did actually suspect this was the case (hence the question). I'm interested in the question as described by @hpchavaz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not be aligned, because by using `.value` (which, by the way, is deprecated in favor of `.to_numpy()`), which returns the underlying numpy array, you remove all index/column information, so alignment is not possible.

Here's one solution to preserve the alignment:

```
df.loc['qux', 'a'] = df.loc['qux', 'a'].index.map(df.loc['bar', 'a'].to_dict())
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                 a   b
first second          
bar   two      1.0   2
      one      3.0   4
baz   one      5.0   6
      two      7.0   8
foo   one      9.0  10
      two     11.0  12
qux   one      3.0  14
      two      1.0  16
```